# What's a good way to interact with Spree's cart/products from Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm bolting Spree onto an existing app. In my app's pages, to display a subset of products I'm currently using the taxon id to access Spree::Product. Same with orders: from the app code I do "Spree::Order.find(session[:order_id])" (so I can display # of items in cart outside of Spree pages)

This seems heavy handed... should I be customizing Spree instead (rewrite some pages), or spinning it up as a separate instance and making API calls, etc.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spree has a module called `Spree::ControllerHelpers::CurrentOrder` that you could include into your `ApplicationController`. This would make the `current_order` method available in all views for your application.

Comment: How does a person make this work? I try to include this module in application_controller.rb and receive an error of ```uninitialized constant Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::CurrentOrder``` every time.

Comment: @wrburgess: What version of Spree?

Comment: Note that the module has changed names recently to just `Order`: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/order.rb

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear (i don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve) and i don't know Spree well, but here are some elements of answer.

- **to override a view** (usually works with most namespaced plugins and engines), just drop a file with the same name and path in your main app tree, for example if you want to override `products/show.html.erb`, just drop it in `app/views/spree/products/show.html.erb`. Be careful, your view will be rendered *from the corresponding spree controller*, so you may not have access to your usual helpers
- **to override a controller** do the same. You can also use inheritance if you want just a little customisation...
- **to render a spree view inside one of yours** just use `render :file =>` and point out to the right path inside the gem.

that's it, the only other thing you will need is to [dive a bit inside the spree gem](https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/core) in order to know which files you want to override / which classes you want to inherit from. A little bit of reading about [engines](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) wouldn't hurt, too.